# Решите, представляет ли строка число

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как вывести функцию `is_number`, которая будет принимать строку в качестве параметра и возвращать `True`, если эта строка является допустимой нотацией действительного числа, или же, в противном случае `false`.
Выглядеть должно так:

`def is_number(string: str) -> bool:`

`>>> is_number('3')`

`True`

`>>> is_number('3.3')`

`True`

`>>> is_number('6e-34')`

`True`

`>>> is_number('0.0.0')`

`False`

`>>> is_number('five')`

`False`

`raise NotImplementedError()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
def is_number(value: str) -> bool:
    try:
        float(value)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

print(is_number('3'))  # True
print(is_number('3.3'))  # True
print(is_number('6e-34'))  # True
print(is_number('0.0.0'))  # False
print(is_number('five'))  # False
```